How to Use parameterized ViewModelClass
i am gatting stuck at on place by follwing the video tutorial.. the metter is this that i am Following the Tutorial Of MVVM which tell me that if your viewmodel class has parameters then you have to make a factory class which extends with viewmodelprovider.Factory but the tutorials code ide automaticaly sugust that you should override function but in my case it do not give any suggestion.
how to Fix that? i am not understaing this
